# Pretending a file is in subdirectory with .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I have a web application, and it has a RESTful PHP backend that uses Zend framework (which does its own URL rewriting magic).

The problem is, my backend's entry-page is `api.php` and the endpoints look like:

```
api.php/resource1
api.php/resource2/id
```

All I want to do is remove the `.php` file extension so my URLs look a little cleaner.

Is there any way of doing this without removing the file extension from the PHP file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite rule in *.htaccess*:

```
RewriteRule  ^test(/.*)?$ test.php?path=$1
```

Contents of `test.php`:

```
<?php 
 if($_GET['path']){
   echo ($_GET['path']);
 }
?>
```

Then when I hit `/test/foo/bar` on my server, the PHP page prints out `/foo/bar`.

Comment: Sorry dude, doesn't work for me. I'm pretty sure this is something to do with ``.htaccess`` rules conflicting with Zend Framework's own URL rewriting stuff. After adding your rule to my ``.htaccess`` file, it just gives me a 404 :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this to just remove `.php`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /.php/$1 [L]
```